# In CentOS, can not connect ftp. (ftp was set by vsftp)

Tags: ftp, centos, vsftpd

vsftpd‘s configuration:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

In fileZilla, I can connect my ftp which its configuration is :

```
encryption: common FTP(insecurity）,protocol: FTP
```

As for folder( or browser), I can not connect it. I seem that connection dimension. But I don't know how to deal with :(

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config , add this code:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

That will be fine.